# Retrieving Uri List from Firebase Database to a RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am working on a social media-like app.
I managed to retrieve single values from database and displayed it on a recycler view.

However, I cannot figure out how to retrieve a list of Images' Uris to populate the recycler view with.

Here is my onBindViewHolder snippet:

```
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull Posts model) {

    holder.setUserName(model.getUserName());
    holder.setProfileImage(model.getProfileImage());
    holder.setOpinionContent(model.getOpinionContent());

    holder.mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String userId = getRef(position).getKey(); //unique user id for every user
            String publisherId = holder.setUserId(model.getUserId());
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), FriendProfile.class);
            profileIntent.putExtra("userId", publisherId);
            startActivity(profileIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

and my ViewHolder:

```
public static class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;

    public PostsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
        ImageView myImage = mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        Picasso.get().load(profileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_image_24).into(myImage);
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        TextView myName = mView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        myName.setText(userName);
    }

    public void setOpinionContent(String opinionContent) {
        TextView myContent = mView.findViewById(R.id.opinion_content);
        myContent.setText(opinionContent);
    }
    public String setUserId(String userId) {
        userId = userId;
        return userId;
    }

    }
```

and my model class:

```
package com.example.domino;

public class Posts {
    String profileImage;
    String userName;
    String OpinionContent;
    String userId;


    public Posts(){
    }

    public Posts(String profileImage, String userName, String opinionContent, String userId) {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
        this.userName = userName;
        OpinionContent = opinionContent;
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }

    public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getOpinionContent() {
        return OpinionContent;
    }

    public void setOpinionContent(String opinionContent) {
        OpinionContent = opinionContent;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

and my Firebase Database:

[image: I cannot embed a picture so here is an autogenerated image link]

So I want to populate my recycler view with multiple images, so in order to do that, I need to be able to configure my database uri list with my model class that I use along with my recycler adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a wrong implementation on ViewHolder Creation and assign values. you shound not link properties like text views get each time from resouces. try to get them all when its init with constructor.

```
package com.pos.aero;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.List;

public class PostViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostViewAdapter.PostsViewHolder> {

List<Model> list;

public PostViewAdapter(List<PostalAddress> list){
    this.list = list;
}

@NonNull
@NotNull
@Override
public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull PostsViewHolder postsViewHolder, int i) {
    Model model = list.get(i);
    Picasso.get().load(model.getProfileImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_image_24).into(postsViewHolder.myImage);
    postsViewHolder.myName.setText(model.getUserName());
    postsViewHolder.myContent.setText(model.getOpinionContent());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

class PostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView myImage;
    TextView myName;
    TextView  myContent;
    public PostsViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        myImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        myName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        myContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.opinion_content);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // OnClick Listener implements here
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

try to click onlick listerner inside the inner class RecyclerView Constructor method.

everytime you scroll onBindViewHolder will call the method and update the viewHolder.

same view holder is repeating with resources but not data. you have to link those data in onBindViewHolder.

i have edited your recycler here and update. please try this way. let me know any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I'll try it and let you know. Looking forward for answers to my query tho, if you can help please.

Comment: Okay I tried it and it works fine. Now I how can I get multiple images from my database to my model class.